# how to show database on listview visual basic net

Tags: vb.net, listview

I have a problem showing a database in a ListView in vb.net. It's not an error but it only shows one column in the ListView. Here is my code:

```
MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM TSiswa WHERE Nama = '" & txtNama.Text & "' ", comm)
adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
Dim dt As New DataTable
adapter.Fill(dt)
For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
    With ListView1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i)("Nama"))
    End With
Next
```

I have tried this code too:

```
With .Items(.Items.Count - 1).SubItems
    .Add(dt.Rows(i)("Alamat"))
    .Add(dt.Rows(i)("Kelas"))
End With
```

but it doesn't help.

Comment: very very simple with a DataGridView: `myDGV.DataSource = dt`  The listview is not ideal for db Ops

Comment: Well it won't display the whole row if you're explicitly adding only one column using "ListView1.Items.Add(dt.Rows(i)("Nama"))"

Comment: @Plutonix can you add to my code above please

Answer (score 0):

Try using Do Until loop so you can check every row in your data adapter and in the listviewitem below add another fields from your database to show in every row of your listview.

```
MyCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT *FROM TSiswa WHERE Nama = '" & txtNama.Text & "' ", comm)
 adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(MyCommand)
 Dim dt As New DataTable
 adapter.Fill(dt)

Dim i as integer
Do Until i = dt.Rows.Count
  'FIELDS FROM YOUR TABLE
  dim lvt as new listviewitem
  lvt.subitems.add(dt.Rows(i)("Nama"))
Listview1.items.add(lvt)

i=i+1
Loop
```